# Is there any way to include (continue ) python variable inside function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here i created some function like

```
def common_function():
    if i==3:
       continue
```

and

```
for i in range(0,10):
    common_function(i)
```

this is simple example, In my code i create common function later i want to used that on multiple place but this cannot be applied.
Is there any way to do that..

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. You define a function without input arguments, but then call it with an input argument.

Comment: Try to explain what you want to achieve and show the code you're having trouble with. What you've shown here is not runnable due to TypeError

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue a for-loop in certain situations, you can use this code snippet:

```
def action_inside_loop(i):
    if i == 3:
        return
    print(f'Doing something with index {i}')

for i in range(5):
    action_inside_loop(i)
```

This results in the output:

```
Doing something with index 0
Doing something with index 1
Doing something with index 2
Doing something with index 4
```

If on the other hand, you want to break out of a for-loop in certain situations, you can use this code snippet:

```
def action_inside_loop(i):
    if i == 3:
        return False
    print(f'Doing something with index {i}')
    return True

for i in range(5):
    should_continue = action_inside_loop(i) 
    if not should_continue:
        break
```

This results in the output:

```
Doing something with index 0
Doing something with index 1
Doing something with index 2
```

Comment: Did you notice the SyntaxError in your last code fragment?

Comment: I missed that, thanks for pointing it out! I have renamed `continue` now to `should_continue`.